# python: name mangling in a dynamically created class

Tags: python, python-3.x, name-mangling, dynamic-class-creation

I want to do something like this

```
def make_class(name : str)->type:
    class Ret:
       __name__ = name
       def __init__(self):
           self.__x = 0
    return Ret

A = make_class('A')
a = A()
assert a._A__x == 0
```

Basically, what I want is to create a type so that it mangles its members according to a dynamic identifier, but the above example doesn't work. Metaclasses don't either.

The only solutions I can think of are:

exec the entire class definition

```
exec("""
class {}:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 0
""".format(name))
```

or set the attribute via getattr

```
class Ret:
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self,'_'+name+"__x",0)
```

but both of them are unattractive for various reasons, is there a right way to do this?

Comment: Note, `exec(...)` is how `namedtuple` is actually implemented, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python name mangling is fundamentally static. It is performed at bytecode compilation time, before your function's `name` argument is available. To invoke this mechanism dynamically, you would have to compile code dynamically, which means you would have to use `exec` or something like it.